# smartdiagram tabular inside additions nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, smartdiagram

I have the following diagram, created with tikz smartdiagram. As you can see, it's possible to add a tabular inside a normal block. But is it possible to add a tabular, similar the existing one, inside an additional node? If not, has someone an idea how to create a diagramm like that?

[image: diagram]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,halfparskip,headsepline,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}



\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \vspace{40mm}\par
    \begin{center}
        \smartdiagramset{%
            back arrow disabled=true,
            module minimum width=4cm,
            module minimum height=4cm,
            module x sep=5cm,
            text width=4cm,
            arrow style=<-,
            additions={
                additional item offset=1cm,
                additional item fill color=colours!!+!20,
                additional item border color=colours!!,
                additional arrow color=red,
                additional item width=4cm,
                additional item height=4cm,
                additional item text width=4cm,
                additional item bottom color=red!50,
                additional item shadow=drop shadow,
            }
        }
        \smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
            accelerometer
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                Name & Unit\\ \hline
                accelerationX & g\\
                accelerationY & g\\
                accelerationZ & g\\ 
            \end{tabular}, Block
        }{below of module2/Output,right of module2/gyroscope, above of module2/magnetometer
    }
    \smartdiagramconnect{->}{module2/additional-module1}        \smartdiagramconnect{->}{additional-module2/module2}
    \smartdiagramconnect{->}{additional-module3/module2}
\end{center}
\vspace{50mm}\par
\label{tab:gyroMeanOffsetCorrectionSchema}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\captionof{figure}{gyroMeanOffsetCorrection Schema}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the error I get when I add a tabular to an additional node is:
Use of \@xs@StrCut@@ doesn't match its definition. }

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. Your MWE works and gives showed result. I can not reproduce mentioned error.

Comment: If there is a problem, it is due to smartdiagram package (which appears to be more work than doing without).  The contents of TikZ nodes should be independent or one another.

Comment: Have you tried saving the tabular in a box first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine if you save the tabular in a box first. Making the code in the question a bit more minimal, for example, by removing some of the irrelevancies:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}
\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}
\smartdiagramset{%
  back arrow disabled=true,
  module minimum width=4cm,
  module minimum height=4cm,
  module x sep=5cm,
  text width=4cm,
  arrow style=<-,
  additions={
    additional item offset=1cm,
    additional item fill color=colours!!+!20,
    additional item border color=colours!!,
    additional arrow color=red,
    additional item width=4cm,
    additional item height=4cm,
    additional item text width=4cm,
    additional item bottom color=red!50,
    additional item shadow=drop shadow,
  }
}
\vspace*{50mm}
\newsavebox\outputbox
\sbox\outputbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Name & Unit\\ \hline
    accelerationX & g\\
    accelerationY & g\\
    accelerationZ & g\\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
  accelerometer
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Name & Unit\\ \hline
    accelerationX & g\\
    accelerationY & g\\
    accelerationZ & g\\
  \end{tabular}, Block
}{%
  below of module2/Output \usebox\outputbox,
  right of module2/gyroscope, above of module2/magnetometer
}
\smartdiagramconnect{->}{module2/additional-module1}        \smartdiagramconnect{->}{additional-module2/module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{->}{additional-module3/module2}
\end{document}
```

[image: saved tabular as addition]

Off-topic:

- `\label` must come ***after*** `\caption`.
- `\captionof` is only required outside the relevant float kind. Within a `figure` environment, use `\caption`.
- Don't load packages you don't need; don't load redundant packages; don't load packages with different options. `color` can go. So can `graphicx`.
- Don't use the `H` specifier for `figure`. It is problematic and should better be avoided in 99% of cases.
- Use `\centering` within `figure`, `table` etc. and the `center` environment outside.
- `halfparskip,headsepline` are not valid options for this class.
- `a4paper` will give strange results when using a standard class without `geometry`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it worked fine! I try to observe you off-topic notes. Thanks a lot for them too.